# How to determine the equation of the circle which cover all the root and have least area

Tags: complex-analysis

> Gauss–Lucas theorem:
>   If P is a (nonconstant) polynomial with complex coefficients, all zeros of P' belong to the convex hull of the set of zeros of P.

so, for every polynomial $P=\sum a_i x^i$ there exist a circle cover all the zero of $P^{(n)}$ on complex plane.

How to determine the equation of the circle which cover all the root and have least area

Comment: This is an interesting question that is outside my area of expertise. My intuition is that it is very hard (or at least an open problem) to determine an explicit formula for this circle in terms of, say, the coefficients and roots of $P$. This stems from the fact that the related claim of [Sendov's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendov's_conjecture) is still wide open for polynomials of degree larger than $7 \pm \varepsilon$.

Comment: Locating the zeros of polynomials (or entire functions) is a very big and open field in mathematics, so answering this question with precision is very difficult, as many aspects of this are unknown. 

You might want to look into Jensen's Formula or Jensen circles or possibly the polar derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [the smallest circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) and appears to be hard in general.
In particular, there appears to be no closed form for the answer; only algorithms.

Exploiting the fact that $P$ is a polynomial does not give you any advantage over just considering a set of $n$ points.  It's possible that the problem is simpler to solve if you start with the coefficients of the polynomial rather than the explicit roots, but if this were so then you could solve the original problem simply by computing the coefficients from the roots (which is easy).  Therefore, I doubt this is the case.